# The names of static files are specified without the static url

Tags: django

Django. The names of static files are specified without the static url.
Example: `<img src="my.png" />`
How to do it? Thank you!

Comment: What did you try thus far and what problem do you encounter?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have static files setup to be served correctly (i.e. they're served by nginx/apache for you or you're running with DEBUG=True) in your template you need

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% static "path/under/your/static/file/folder.gif" %}
```

if that is what you're doing and it isn't working its likely your STATIC_URL, STATIC_ROOT etc are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% static "/challenge.x.png" as mono %}
<img src="{{mono }}"
```

return `<img src="/static/challenge.x.png" />`

correct is `<img src="challenge.x.png" />`